# High no-load current and speed in a brushed DC motor

Tags: dc-motor

**TL;DR**

Small (20 mm dia.), (very) cheap, permanent magnet brushed DC motor draws a lot of current and runs faster than expected above certain RPM at no load. Up to that point it follows the textbook faithfully. Why?

**No so short description**

The very well-known simple model for a permanent magnet brushed DC motor consists of a \$V_{emf}\$ source and armature resistance \$R\$. When armature current \$I\$ flows, the terminal voltage is:

$$V=V_{emf}+IR$$

The angular velocity of the motor is in linear relation to \$V_{emf}\$:

$$\omega=KV_{emf}$$

The torque is also in linear relation to \$I\$:

$$T=I/K$$

The theory is simple and clear, and it is well founded in relatively simple physics (if someone dares to call magnetic circuits simple). However, I have a DC motor application where I needed to characterize a brushed DC motor. Unfortunately, the small mechanical wonder has not read its physics books and declines to obey follow the simple model.

I made a series of measurements where the armature current \$I\$ and input voltage \$V\$ were recorded at fixed speeds (as verified by optical speed measurement) with no external load. The simple theory says that due to Coulomb friction \$I\$ should be constant (as the bearing and brush friction represent constant \$T\$). A bit more advanced model states that there may be viscous friction, air resistance, and other factors which may increase the no-load torque at high speeds.

The current (and supposedly torque) vs. rotational speed (in rpm) is plotted below:
[image: Current vs. rotational speed]
So, everything goes according to the textbook until around 3000 rpm (the high static friction is just as expected at 0 rpm). Above that something happens. Either there is some highly non-linear friction component, or our \$I\$ vs. \$T\$ relation breaks.

To see what happens, I measured the armature resistance \$R\$ which turned out to be quite exactly 50 ohms. The measurement was carried out by two different methods: direct measurement with a multimeter, and stall current measurements at different voltage levels. The two methods agree very well.

\$V_{emf}\$ cannot be measured directly, but I used two different indirect methods to determine it. The first method was using the simple model, which gives \$V_{emf}=V-IR\$. The second method is by dividing the rotation speed in rpm by 718 1/min/V (or 75.2 rad/s/V in more standard units). These calculations and direct measurements are shown in the graph below:
[image: Measurements and calculated V_emf]
The voltage (\$V\$ and calculated \$V_{emf}\$) scale is on the left, current (\$I\$) on the right. Measurements are plotted in solid line, calculations as dotted lines.

It can be seen that the match between the two \$V_{emf}\$ models is exceptionally good up to around 3000 rpm (spot on within measurement uncertainty, errors < 0.2 %). But then something odd happens, and the motor runs much faster than what the simple model indicates.

So, at high speeds the motor draws excessive current and is faster than it should be. I have gone through a couple of hypotheses but am not satisfied with any of them. These hypotheses are of course all limited by understanding, so there may be grand mistakes in them.

**Hypothesis I: Non-linear friction losses** There are a lot of different mechanical losses and with the dirt cheap bearings, etc. there might be different velocity-dependent friction mechanisms. Even turbulent air losses could be an explanation. This explanation, unfortunately, does not explain why the simple torque, voltage, current, speed relation falls apart.

**Hypothesis II: Armature reaction** This has the familiar smell of field weakening (higher speed and current). However, field weakening in a permanent magnet motor happens only at high loads (a lot of current flowing through the armature), and here we have no external load. Field weakening should not be dependent on the speed.

**Hypothesis III: Core saturation** Core saturation would look like field weakening, but it has the same property of occurring under high loads.

**Hypothesis IV: Eddy currents** This phenomenon has something to do with the rotational velocity. Eddy currents in the armature might be one explanation because they are frequency-dependent (\$f^2\$), but they should essentially brake down the rotor and thus look like mechanical losses, which leads us to the same problem as Hypothesis I.

**Hypothesis V: Commutation** Maybe the higher velocity between the brushes and slip rings makes the brush contact worse. All sorts of non-linear behaviour would be expected, jumping, sparkin, etc. However, this does not explain the increase in rotational velocity (unless bad commutation causes something inductive to happen in the armature which would then increase the effective voltage). Rather, I would expect bad contact to be seen as increased armature resistance and thus slower rotation without any significant changes in the armature current.

Any ideas? The only loss I am sure about is that I am at a loss...

Comment: Can currents be induced in the magnet weaken the magnet?

Comment: Anything but 2,3. Field weakening is not possible unless you weaken the PM field with external one. Core saturation will happen at high currents, not at no load. I don't understand your estimated curve, it shall be linear.

Comment: Your "measured" voltage curve looks spot on, so I have some doubts about your current measurement.  The motor will have a high torque ripple and an associated current ripple.  I would be wary of believing a current meter, especially if it's one on a power supply.  Best bet is to measure the voltage across a sense resistor with a scope - I wouldn't be surprised if it's a measurement problem.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead This is what I suspected first. Spiky currents are not the easiest to measure. The current measurements are somewhat fluctuating at low RPMs due to interference between the current integration period of the meter and commutation frequency of the motor, but at higher currents they are repeatable and consistent even when taken with different instruments.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Note that the horizontal axis is the terminal voltage, not EMF. So, the increase in current should decrease the EMF and thus the rpm, but it does not. As far as I understand, even PM motors are susceptible to armature reaction, as the total magnetic field is a sum of the PM field and the (relatively smaller) perpendicular field produced by the armature current. This will rotate the total field. However, the phenomenon should depend on the armature current, not speed, and it is usually taken as negligible in small motors.

Comment: @DKNguyen An interesting thought! My understanding, however, is that the field created by the armature current should be more or less stationary and perpendicular to the PM field, so this should not happen. But I do agree that any speed-related phenomenon wekaning the field would sound like a good candidate.

Comment: Interesting.  How did you measure the armature resistance?  Through the brushes with a meter?  Maybe try applying a small voltage with a locked rotor and do the math.  If you used an ohmmeter, there could be an error here.  I know I'm harping on measurement errors, but you're always most scared of the dog that bit you.

Comment: Otherwise maybe the armature inductance contributes to a phase shift in the relationship between the voltage and current.  You might be able to test this with a locked rotor and a function generator.  I just can't get may brain past your voltage curve.

Comment: thixotropic grease in the bearings perhaps.

Comment: @Jasen I thought of that in the first place; actually there was a gearhead attached to the motor when I started examining it, and I immediately blamed the gears and grease. However, if there was any mechanism which increases friction, it should increase the current and decrease speed. Now the speed does not go down even though the current increases.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead I share your experience on dubious measurements, the same dog has bitten me several times. I added some explanations to my question, both regarding to the armature resistance measurement and the plot (which I updated to be hopefully clearer).

Comment: Maybe look at the current waveform at different speeds - your instantaneous current may have some commutation effect.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead Yup. It seems it is time to whip up some suitable arrangement for that. My excuse for not measuring the current waveform before was that I did not want to build an amplifier. But I do not need to, because I can use a largish sense resistor, as I am running at constant speed and load. Another idea I came across is that I'll run some load tests with constant input voltage to see what happens to the current and speed. (At some point I'll have to give up and do something more productive, but this little motor was escalated onto my desk, and I want to understand it.)

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies - I'd be interested to know how it turns out.